# How to add negative values to bar graph using d3 node?

Tags: node.js, svg, d3.js

I want to add negative values in bar graph using d3 node.
My code is

```
const D3Node = require('d3-node');
const fs = require('fs');
const sharp = require('sharp');


const options = {
   selector: '#chart',
   container: '<div id="container"><div id="chart"></div></div>'
 };
 
 // Create a d3-node object with the selector and the required d3 module. 
 const d3n = new D3Node(options);

 const d3=d3n.d3
 
 const margin = {
  top: 10, right: 5, bottom: 30, left: 5 
 };
 const width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
 const height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 const svgWidth = width + margin.left + margin.right;
 const svgHeight = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;
 
 // Create an svg element with the width and height defined.
 const svg = d3n.createSVG(svgWidth, svgHeight);


 const tempData = [{ year: 2020, value: 100 }, { year: 2019, value: -200 }, { year: 2018, value: 30 }, { year: 2017, value: 50 }, { year: 2016, value: 80 }];


 // Create the scales for x-axis and y-axis.
 const xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.4);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

let yMax = d3.max(tempData, (d) => { return d.value; });
yMax += yMax * 0.3;


let yMin = d3.max(tempData, (d) => { return d.value; });
yMin += yMin * 0.3;
xScale.domain(tempData.map((d) => { return d.year; }));
yScale.domain([0, yMax]);




// Set the background of the entire svg to a desired color. This will make the background look uniform on everyone's computer.
svg.append('rect')
   .attr('width', '100%')
   .attr('height', '100%')
   .style('fill', 'white');

// Add a title text to your bar chart. 
svg.append('text')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(150,0)')
 .attr('x', 50)
 .attr('y', 50)
 .attr('font-size', '24px')
 .text('Node and D3 Bar chart');

// Append a group element to which the bars and axes will be added to.
svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${ 100 },${ 100 })`);




// Appending x-axis
svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', `translate(50,${ height })`)
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
.append('text')
.attr('y', height - 380)
.attr('x', width - 500)
.attr('text-anchor', 'end')
.attr('stroke', 'black')
.attr('font-size', '20px')
.text('Year');


// Appending y-aixs
svg.append('g')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(50,0)')
 .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat((d) => {
   return `$${ d }`;
 })
   .ticks(5))
 .append('text')
 .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
 .attr('y', 150)
 .attr('x', -150)
 .attr('dy', '-9.1em')
 .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
 .attr('stroke', 'black')
 .attr('font-size', '20px')
 .text('Cost');


   // Appending the bars
   svg.selectAll('.bar')
   .data(tempData)
   .enter().append('rect')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(50,0)')
   .attr('class', 'bar')
   .attr('x', (d) => { return xScale(d.year); })
   .attr('y', (d) => { return yScale(d.value); })
   .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
   .attr('height', (d) => { return height - yScale(d.value); })
   .style('fill', 'orange');


   
// Create a SVG. 
fs.writeFileSync('out.svg', d3n.svgString());

// Convert the SVG into a PNG. 
sharp('out.svg')
   .png()
   .toFile('sharp.png')
   .then((info) => {
       console.log('Svg to Png conversion completed', info);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
   });
```

now code works for positive value.
but when I insert any negative value its graph get sets to zero.
I am using nodejs and i want to generate svg file. so for generating files i am using d3-node module i am able to generate graph with positive data but when i insert negative data while generating graph all negative values are showing as zero.

Comment: The `y` scale's `domain` needs to be adapted, in order to support negative values. Currently, it goes from 0 to yMax: `yScale.domain([0, yMax]);` . Calculate yMin and set it to `yScale.domain([yMin, yMax]);`

Comment: @Mehdi  i have tried but its not working. if we set domain from yMin to yMax then all the bars are showing similar values i.e 200